# Bourbon's @font-face mixin finds the font but wont display it

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass, bourbon

I'm trying to get this font displayed on the header of my page using bourbon's font-face mixin.

My code is as follows:

```
@include font-face(3dumb, '3dumb/3Dumb-webfont', normal, $asset-pipeline: true)

.header {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 3dumb;
};
```

This should set the font for my .header to 3dumb but it doesn't. the font is instead the default browser font.

My font is stored in assets/fonts/3dumb and I'm using rails 4.

Does anyone here know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the font by default but not header, maybe you are missing the ' '

`.header {
    font-family: '3dumb';
}`

Comment: somehow that changed the font to a serif from a sans-serif

Comment: Putting both the font name in the font-face call and the font-family call made it work. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your font is in the folder `app/assets/fonts`. (no subfolder)
2. Check for any spelling / capitalization mistakes

If you want to use your font from `vendor/assets/fonts` then you can add the following to your application.rb:

```
app.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')
app.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Try the following CSS instead:

```
@include font-face(3dumbregular, '3Dumb-webfont', normal, $asset-pipeline: true)

.header {
    font-family: '3dumbregular';
}
```

Comment: I know it's finding the font because it throws a sprockets error if it doesn't... so it's not one of the obvious spelling mistake errors I'm afraid :(